# Newbie can't get Tomcat to reload Flex/BlazeDS application

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds

I'm an experienced 'old school' programmer, but new to Tomcat and Flex. I've followed the getting started for BlazeDS. I'm making changes to the Flex code using Flex Builder 3, but I just can't get the changes to show up when I refresh the page on my client. Server and client are separate physical machines, I've even re-started the server hardware. One curious thing, even when I re-started the server I didn't have to re-login to the Tomcat manager page - I didn't restart my client, I guess it remembers my session?

TIA, getting frustrated - like my flex page is 'write once'.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be cached by the browser. I set the expiry of the page and disabled caching as detailed [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/webdesign/prevent_caching_of_web_pages_by_browsers.php3). Sorry for the trouble.